# Handle Sync in react redux saga

Tags: reactjs, synchronization, react-redux, yield, redux-saga

User will enter name email and order information , including payment details.
On clicking buy now button from a form i plan to do the following steps:

- Create User by api call.
- Automatically login and fetch the token by
  api call.
- Using form data create an order by api call.
- Get payment provider token by api call.
- Proceed to payment page.

Using React-redux-saga for the front end.

Please below the code for it:

```
function* addToCartCamp(action) {
  try {

    // User creation and login
    yield put({ type: authActions.AUTH_REGISTER_REQUEST, ...createUser });
    yield put({ type: authActions.AUTH_REGISTER_SUCCESS, ...userdata });
    yield put({ type: authActions.AUTH_LOGIN_REQUEST, ...login });

    //Create order
    const { data } = yield orderAPI.addToCartCamp(action);
    yield put({ type: orderActions.ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS, ...data });
    yield put({ type: orderActions.GET_DETAIL_ORDER_REQUEST, ...{orderId: order_id} });

    //Handle Payment
     if(action.payment.method === 'creditCard'){
      yield put({ type: orderActions.TOKEN_REQUEST, ...{orderId: order_id} });
     } else{
      yield put({ type: orderActions.BANK_TRANSFER_REQUEST, ...{orderId: order_id} });
     }
  } catch (error) {
      // handle error message
  }
}
```

Can i call multiple Yield put and then api inside the a saga file. When this function is called, the back end starts the order creation process even before the user is created and logged in.

I need all the process to run in sync but they run currently in async.

New to saga and react. How can this be handled.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**: you need to `take()` an action and `call()` the api to yield its result before `put()`ing the success action.

### Example

```
function* addToCartCamp(action) {
  try {
    const action = yield take(authActions.AUTH_REGISTER_REQUEST);
    const userToCreate = action.payload;

    const userData = yield call(authApi.createUser, userToCreate);
    yield put({ type: authActions.AUTH_REGISTER_SUCCESS, userData });

    const sessionData = yield call(authApi.loginUser, userData);
    yield put({ type: authActions.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS, sessionData });

    // ...
  }
}
```

### Additional notes

You have too much going on in one saga in my opinion. Why are you registering a user at the same place where an order gets created? I would split those two use cases into two different sagas because you might have an already signed up user that only needs to login before buying something. Don't handle authentication in your order saga, let the API handle auth failures.

Speaking of which, you should also have actions for FAILURE of api calls. So, when the server returns a 401 because a user is not authorized to go shopping you should `yield put` a specific `orderActions.SOMETHING_FAILURE` action with a reducer that stores the error message, handles pending state etc.

Having a global try catch block makes debugging very difficult and should be avoided. See https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.md (last code example):

```
import Api from './path/to/api'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function fetchProductsApi() {
  return Api.fetch('/products')
    .then(response => ({ response }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }))
}

function* fetchProducts() {
  const { response, error } = yield call(fetchProductsApi)
  if (response) {
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products: response })
  } else {
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I moved the account creation and login to a different button action in the page and rest to a different button action. Works smoothly now with no issues.

Comment: Glad i could help. By the way, you can accept and upvote my answer if it resolved your issue.